# what's the difference between getString() and only String?

Tags: android

When I use this code

```
private val defaultUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.viewpager2demo/drawable/add")
```

I can get the right uri string.
But when I try the similar code like this,

```
private val defaultUri = Uri.parse(getString(R.string.addImage))
```

I got nullpoint error. the string.xml define the R.string.addImage like below

```
<string name="addImage">android.resource://com.example.viewpager2demo/drawable/add</string>
```

The content is same, But first is working, And second is not Working. what's the difference?
Also the log is same

```
Log.d("TAG","getString : " + getString(R.string.addImage))
Log.d("TAG", "defaultUri : " +defaultUri.toString())

D/TAG: getString : android.resource://com.example.viewpager2demo/drawable/add
D/TAG: defaultUri : android.resource://com.example.viewpager2demo/drawable/add
```

Comment: Show the logcat error

Comment: You can't call `getString()` in field initializer; i.e., outside of any class method. That's a `Context` method, and the `Activity` will not yet have been setup to act as a `Context`. If you want to keep that string in your resources, you'll have to wait until at least `onCreate()` to do that call.

Comment: I didn't know the getString() is a Context Method. thank u guys.

Comment: Also I want to know How to find the getString method is Context Method.

Comment: Use getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.addImage);

Comment: Put your cursor on the `getString()` call, and press ctrl+B. That should take you to the declaration, I believe, which will be in `Context`.

Comment: @PrajwalW That won't help. Calling `getApplicationContext()` in a field initializer will throw an Exception, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uri is a path, that's why you are getting your error, try transforming that string resource int a Uri

```
private val defaultUri = Uri.parse(getString(R.string.addImage).toUri())
```

As Mike commented, the nullpointerException is because you are not initializing your references after `onCreate`

To fix it

```
private lateinit var defaultUri:Uri
```

inside onCreate()

```
defaultUri = Uri.parse(getString(R.string.addImage).toUri())
```